# Best practice, how to alter css file in JSF (Solved: How to access JSF 2.0 resources from Managed Bean)

Tags: css, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, managed-bean

I know how to access resources form view, but how can I access JSF resources from Managed Bean for example to edit css file ? Or I shouldn't try to do it at all, and think about another solution ?

**Update**:
The idea was to alter css file by accessing it from Managed Bean @McDowell helped me with that and I'm relay grateful. But as he said it's not relay a good idea. The goal is to give user ability to alter page style (colors, fonts, layout etc.). As I said earlier using style attribute would be hm.. annoying, my second idea is to write custom renderer and generate embedded style sheet but I'm beginner in java EE and JSF so I'm not sure if it is good idea, maybe there is other easier way?

Comment: You can access application resources via the `ExternalContext` (which you can get from the `FacesContext`) but your example use case does not sound like a good use for managed beans. http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentInstance()

Comment: Thx so much, it works but if it's not a good idea then I need to think another way to give user ability to alter page style :S But using bean to alter style attribute of all components would be stupid so I need to generate css file and somehow add it to the view. Maby someone know easy way to do it ?